# performing operations on images uploaded by tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new to Tkinter and python. I am trying to upload two images and then perform some operations on them. The problem is that the `Window` class is loading all at once or the code in running parallel, so the images uploaded after that have been already assigned to `None` since they were uploaded later in the `ScrollableFrame` class and did not have a value earlier.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageOps
import os

# ************************
# Scrollable Frame Class
# ************************
row=0
column=0
imagePaths = []
#Class to generate a frame to add to the GUI with vertical and horizontal scroll bars
class ScrollableFrame(Frame):

    #The Constructor method for the class
    def __init__(self, parent , *args, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)
        #Defining the position of the frame grid
        self.grid(row = row , column = column)

        self.image = None
        self.imageFile = None
        #Defining the vertical scroll bar
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.grid(row=row, column=column+1, sticky=N+S)
        #Defining the horizontal scroll bar
        hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = 'horizontal')
        hscrollbar.grid(row=row+1, column=column, sticky=E+W)
        #Defining the canvas to put the scroll bars on
        canvas = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)
        canvas.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky = N+S+E+W)
        canvas.config( width=800, height = 800 )
        #Defining the scrolling commands (vertically and horizontally )
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
        hscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
        #Defining the scroll region where the scrolling is active
        canvas.config(scrollregion= (0,0,1280,1024))
        self.canvas = canvas

    def openImage(self):

        #Getting the path of the image
        imageFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),title="Select BMP File",filetypes=[("BMP Files",("*.bmp",".png",".jpg",".jpeg",".tif",".tiff"))])
        #Assigning the image value to this frame object
        self.imageFile = imageFile
        if not imageFile:
            return


    def showImage(self):
        #Getting the path of the image
        imageFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),title="Select BMP File",filetypes=[("BMP Files",("*.bmp",".png",".jpg",".jpeg",".tif",".tiff"))])
        #Assigning the image value to this frame object
        self.imageFile = imageFile
        if not imageFile:
            return

        #Checking for the extension of the image
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(imageFile)
        #If it is a .bmp, this means that it is an HD image, where we can directly display it
        if file_extension == '.bmp':
            imageToDisplay = Image.open(imageFile)
            #border = (0, 0, 0, 66) #Decide on the area you want to crop in terms of no. pixels: left, up, right, bottom
            #ImageOps.crop(imageToDisplay, border)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageToDisplay)
            self.image = img
            #print ("Done conversion")
            self.canvas.create_image(row, column, image=self.image, anchor=NW)


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        global row, column,imagePaths
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.pos = []
        self.master.title("BMP Image GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.label = Label(self, text="Instructions: \n 1. Open the HD image. \n 2. Open the EBSD image. \n 3. Open the Color Map image.", anchor=W, justify=LEFT)
        self.label.place(x=1640, y=0)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        self.frame1 = ScrollableFrame(self)
        row=0
        column=1
        self.frame2 = ScrollableFrame(self)


        # File Bar
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Open HD image", command=self.frame1.showImage)
        img = Image.open("original.bmp")
        HD = self.frame2.imageFile
        file.add_command(label="Open EBSD image", command=self.frame2.openImage)
        EBSD = self.frame2.imageFile
        print (HD)
        print (EBSD)



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (1670, 1024))
root.title("BMP Image GUI")
app = Window(root)
app.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

#print (HD)
root.mainloop()
```

So printing the HD and EBSD images is giving `None`. What I am aiming to to make them get the actual value assigned after the upload.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of code and it doesn't run. It also has a few problems. When you are coding complex applications it is best to do it one little piece at a time or you'll have problems finding the problems. Here are a few:

Don't use global variables in an object oriented application. The names `row`, `column` and `imagePaths` should belong to either of the two classes.

The menu doesn't work because you have not implemented it correctly:

```
file = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file) # You need this for it to work
file.add_command(label="Open HD image", command=self.frame1.showImage)
# etc...
```

You are packing `app` twice, once in it's `__init__()` function and once after it's been created (in the global scope).

The scrollable frames are packed in front of the Label with instructions so you can't see it.

Try fixing these problems by writing components, and when each component works then combine them. If there is a problem with any of the components, or if everything works but for one thing, come back here and we will be able to give you a better answer.